# How is $D_n^2=N$ derived from $D_n^2=D_{n-1}^2+1$ considering that $D_1^2=1$ (Feynman Lectures on Physics 6.3)

Tags: probability, expected-value, random-walk, random, means

I don't see how equation 6.8 follows from equation 6.9.
Feynman states in his lecture:

"In general, we should expect for $D_{n-1}^2$ its “expected value” $<D_{n-1}^2>$ (by definition!). 
So $<D_n^2> = <D_{n-1}^2>+1$. 
We have already shown that $D_1^2=1$; it follows then that $<D_n^2> = N$."

equation 6.8: $<D_n^2> = <D_{n-1}^2>+1$

equation 6.9: $<D_n^2> = N$

You can find the full lecture here: [Probability (6.3)](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_06.html)

Could someone explain how to approach this derivation?

Answer (score 1):

Let $D_n^2=E_n$, then $E_n=E_{n-1}+1 \implies E_n-E_{n-1}=1 \implies E_n=n+A$ (Aeithimatic Progression: common difference is $1$ and $A$ is first term). 
One may also do  teslescopic summation to get $E_n=n+A$.
As $E_1=1$, we get$%A=0$. So $E_n=n \implies D_n=\sqrt{n}.$

Comment: I follow you until Let $E_n-E_{n-1}=1$, then you start to introduce variables A and P. What is their meaning? Also, I do not understand the transformation from the expected value to the value n.

Comment: OH! AP means Arithimatic progression: difference of two successive terms is 1.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that $E_n-E_{n-1}=1$ simply implies the difference between two successive terms, called AP. However, what follows up makes no sense to me. What does it take to get $E_n=n+A$ out of $E_n=E_{n-1}+1$?